# Manipulating linkedlists in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Why do we have to pass a pointer to a pointer to manipulate a linked list? Why can't we just pass the pointer? I just dont understand the internals of what is happening logically.

I see it as passing in the pointer to the list would suffice, but apparently not.

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: Post the code in question. Hard to say without knowing your linked list implementation.

Comment: Passing a pointer to the first node *is* sufficient for a basic linked list implementation, but it's impossible to know what the problem is here without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your linked list implementation, but for the sake of argument, if you have implemented, say, a `push` function, like this:

```
typedef struct linked_list linked_list;

struct linked_list
{
    int value;
    linked_list *next;
};

void push(linked_list **head, int value)
{
    linked_list *temp = *head;
    *head = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    (*head)->value = value;
    (*head)->next = temp;
}
```

then the pointer to a pointer is necessary because, otherwise, you would be modifying `push`'s local `head` variable, and not the caller's.

Answer (score 0):

In C if you want to pass a parameter which is possibly modified by the function you pass a pointer to the variable containing the modified value:

```
 void swap(int *i, int *j) // modifies the two parameter.
```

Now if this parameter is itself a pointer, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer. Take for example the function insert which insert a cell in front of a list. If you *represent the list as a pointer to its first element*, then this pointer has to be modified. So you pass a pointer to it:

with

```
typedef struct cell *list

void insert(list *pl, struct cell *pc)
                  ^^
```

Since list is a pointer itself it is a pointer to a pointer since `list *` is the same as `struct cell **`.

Comment: what about an array in a function parameter such as int foo(int* array) when you call it in main like this foo(array); that isnt a pointer to a pointer right

Comment: C array are very special. You don't pass an array but a pointer to it's first element. As long as you only modify the content of the array, only this pointer is needed. But If you need to modifies the memory location of the array (for example to reallocate it because it's growing) then pointer on pointer may be needed (actually, usually pointer on a struct containing a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

There's no one line answer to this

Have at look at page no.12 (push()) in this document: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf

Best explanation according to me.